# Counting number of consecutive zeros in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

i want to count number of consecutive zeros in my Dataframe shown below, help please

```html
  DEC  JAN  FEB  MARCH  APRIL  MAY        consecutive zeros
0    X    X    X      1      0    1              0
1    X    X    X      1      0    1              0
2    0    0    1      0      0    1              2
3    1    0    0      0      1    1              3
4    0    0    0      0      0    1              5
5    X    1    1      0      0    0              3
6    1    0    0      1      0    0              2
7    0    0    0      0      1    0              4
```

Comment: Is possible multiple consecutives?

Comment: Shouldn't that be : `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4]`?

Comment: No, i  need only the consecutive zeros, in row 2 because all the consecutive are two it will return two if one part was 3 then return 3, but in row 3 there are 3 consecutive zeros  return 3 -  @jezrael

Comment: Why is first row output `0`?

Comment: Because there is only one zero, i need consecutives from 0,0 or 0,0,0 etc- @Divakar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my two cents...

Think of all the other non-zero elements as `1`, then you will have a binary code. All you need to do now is find the 'largest interval' where there's no bit flip starting with `0`.

We can write a function and 'apply' with `lambda`

```
def len_consec_zeros(a):
    a = np.array(list(a))    # convert elements to `str`
    rr = np.argwhere(a == '0').ravel()  # find out positions of `0`
    if not rr.size:  # if there are no zeros, return 0
        return 0

    full = np.arange(rr[0], rr[-1]+1)  # get the range of spread of 0s

    # get the indices where `0` was flipped to something else
    diff = np.setdiff1d(full, rr)
    if not diff.size:     # if there are no bit flips, return the 
        return len(full)  # size of the full range

    # break the array into pieces wherever there's a bit flip
    # and the result is the size of the largest chunk
    pos, difs = full[0], []
    for el in diff:
        difs.append(el - pos)
        pos = el + 1

    difs.append(full[-1]+1 - pos)

    # return size of the largest chunk
    res = max(difs) if max(difs) != 1 else 0

    return res
```

Now that you have this function, call it on every row...

```
# join all columns to get a string column

# assuming you have your data in `df`
df['concated'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
df['consecutive_zeros'] = df.concated.apply(lambda x: len_consec_zeros(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

For each row, you want `cumsum(1-row)` with reset at every point when `row == 1`. Then you take the row max.

For example

```
ts = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0])
ts2 = 1-ts
tsgroup = ts.cumsum()

consec_0 = ts2.groupby(tsgroup).transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
consec_0.max()
```

will give you 4 as needed.

Write that in a function and apply to your dataframe

Comment: old post... but I feel this should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach -

```
# Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385183/
def pos_neg_counts(mask):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] != mask[:-1])
    if len(idx)==0: # To handle all 0s or all 1s cases
        if mask[0]:
            return np.array([mask.size]), np.array([0])
        else:
            return np.array([0]), np.array([mask.size])
    else:
        count = np.r_[ [idx[0]+1], idx[1:] - idx[:-1], [mask.size-1-idx[-1]] ]
        if mask[0]:
            return count[::2], count[1::2] # True, False counts
        else:
            return count[1::2], count[::2] # True, False counts

def get_consecutive_zeros(df):
    arr = df.values
    mask = (arr==0) | (arr=='0')
    zero_count = np.array([pos_neg_counts(i)[0].max() for i in mask])
    zero_count[zero_count<2] = 0
    return zero_count
```

Sample run -

```
In [272]: df
Out[272]: 
  DEC JAN FEB  MARCH  APRIL  MAY
0   X   X   X      1      0    1
1   X   X   X      1      0    1
2   0   0   1      0      0    1
3   1   0   0      0      1    1
4   0   0   0      0      0    1
5   X   1   1      0      0    0
6   1   0   0      1      0    0
7   0   0   0      0      1    0

In [273]: df['consecutive_zeros'] = get_consecutive_zeros(df)

In [274]: df
Out[274]: 
  DEC JAN FEB  MARCH  APRIL  MAY  consecutive_zeros
0   X   X   X      1      0    1                  0
1   X   X   X      1      0    1                  0
2   0   0   1      0      0    1                  2
3   1   0   0      0      1    1                  3
4   0   0   0      0      0    1                  5
5   X   1   1      0      0    0                  3
6   1   0   0      1      0    0                  2
7   0   0   0      0      1    0                  4
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar it actually worked very well in one of my dataset but it now giving me this error  df2['consecutive_zeros'] = get_consecutive_zeros(df2)
  File "cross.py", line 87, in get_consecutive_zeros
    zero_count = np.array([pos_neg_counts(i)[0].max() for i in mask])
  File "cross.py", line 78, in pos_neg_counts
    count = np.concatenate(([idx[0]+1], idx[1:] - idx[:-1], [mask.size-1-idx[-1]
]))
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: @SarahMwamlima Think you were using the codes before my latest edit? Can you check again with the latest code in my post? I had added : `if len(idx)==0:` just for those cases.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked very perfect, though am very new to pandas and numpy this is so cool. cheers